# How To Match Dictionary Values with Array Values & Only Output One

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, match

I'm messing around with the songkick api to retrieve concert data and I'm writing a program that pulls upcoming concerts info for a set of artists that I have inputted as an array with the artist name and their accompanying artist id from the songkick api. When making requests I'm iterating through this array so that my program checks upcoming shows for each artist within the range of dates I have inputted as part of parameters. I have been able to extract all of the info I am looking for thus far, but I have noticed in my output that some shows have multiple artists on the bill and I'm wondering the best way to match the artist id of each request iteration with the artist id for each show and only output the matches. I am only interested in outputting the artist names from my list and not every artist that is billed for each show. For example, if one of the artists in my list I'm iterating through various id's for is EarthGang, in my list they'd appear as (`'EarthGang', '8321948'`) where the number is the artist id that songkick associates with them.

If they have any shows during the range of dates, the output currently will show an individual show as:

`[{'artistID': [8321948], 'date': '2020-01-22', 'name': ['EarthGang'], 'city': 'Hollywood, CA, US'}]`

The output will show a concert where other artists are booked as well as:

`[{'artistID': [8321948, 5965579], 'date': '2020-01-22', 'name': ['EarthGang', 'Mick Jenkins'], 'city': 'Hollywood, CA, US'}]`.

Desired output is for regardless of number of artistIDs for each formatted_show, only output the 'artistID' and 'name' for those we are tracking.

Turn

`[{'artistID': [8321948, 5965579], 'date': '2020-01-22', 'name': ['EarthGang', 'Mick Jenkins'], 'city': 'Hollywood, CA, US'}]`

Into

`[{'artistID': [8321948], 'date': '2020-01-22', 'name': ['EarthGang'], 'city': 'Hollywood, CA, US'}]`

I'm looking for both instances to only show the EarthGang name and ID. Here is a link to [songkick json hierarchy](https://www.songkick.com/developer/upcoming-events-for-artist)

Here is some code and what I've attempted thus far:

```
import requests

# artists we want to track
artist_ids = [
    ('ASAP Rocky', '4610868'), ('Petit Biscuit', '8630279'), ('EARTHGANG', '8321948'), ('Taylor Janzen', '9758294')
]

# fetch events based on artist_ids we are tracking and date range
for artist_id in artist_ids:

    params = {
        'apikey': 'API_KEY',
        'min_date': '2020-01-20',
        'max_date': '2020-01-28'
    }

    r = requests.get('https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/' + artist_id[1] + '/calendar.json', params=params)
    response = r.json()

    shows = response['resultsPage']['results']

    for show in shows:
        try:
           shows = shows['event']

            # reformatting response
            formatted_shows = [{
                'artistID': [perf['artist']['id'] for perf in s['performance']],
                'date': s['start']['date'],
                'name': [perf['artist']['displayName'] for perf in s['performance']],
                'city': s['location']['city']
                }
                for s in shows if len(s['performance']) > 0

                ]
            for sub in formatted_shows:
                if sub['artistID'] == artist_id[1]:
                    sub['name'] = artist_id[0]
                print(sub)
```

I'm attaching a photo of output of a show that has one artist billed and another that has multiple artists billed. Let's say 'Taylor Janzen' is who I'm interested in outputting and not the other artist, how would I go about matching her artistID's from the formatted_shows variable and the artists_id variable to only output her and not every artist billed on each iteration? [image]

Comment: what is the desired output? please edit the post to include that

Comment: @aws_apprentice just added. Thought I made it transparent enough in original post, but hopefully that helps! thanks for looking through!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this. It was actually quite simple. Instead of print(sub) I have gone for:

```
for sub in formatted_shows:
    if sub['artistID'] == artist_id[1]:
          sub['name'] = artist_id[0]
    new_show = artist_id[1]
    new_show_name = artist_id[0]
    print(new_show, new_show_name, sub['date'], sub['city'])
```

Creating a new variable that would just access the indexes of my original array to output those names only worked perfectly!